# Converting EEG osc signal as midi for use in Ableton Live

Tags: midi, osc, max-msp-jitter, ableton-live

I have EEG signal that is processed using [openvibe](http://openvibe.inria.fr/), which outputs the signal as osc. Using the [livegrabber](https://www.showsync.com/tools) I was able to receive the signal in ableton (see pic). However, now I’m stuck on how I can make use of this signal. I want to convert it into midi to control vst parameters in Ableton. Can anyone give me pointers?

[image: livegrabber ableton live]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer, linking to the conversation from the same question on the Showsync forum: https://forum.showsync.com/t/integrating-eeg-osc-signal-with-ableton/794/2